# Count how many times each pair of item has same order id in SQL

Tags: sql, aggregation, self-join

I want to find the pairs of skuid that are ordered more frequently., and then view these pairs.
My **SKU** table has 2 columns: **skuid** and **orderid**.
For example:

```
orderid | skuid
--------|---------
1       | a
1       | b
1       | c
3       | a
3       | b   
3       | d   
3       | c   
5       | a   
5       | b
```

So, in this case it would be:
skuid (a,b) pair appears 3 times and (a,c), (b,c) pair appears 2 times.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which database are you using?  Also, doesn't `b,c` appear twice (for id 1 and 3)?

Comment: Yes! i re-editedthe question. you are right. What do you mean database?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `(orderid, skuid)` is unique:

```
SELECT t1.skuid
    ,t2.skuid
    ,COUNT(*) "count"
FROM UnnamedTable t1
INNER JOIN UnnamedTable t2
    ON  t1.orderid = t2.orderid
    AND t1.skuid   < t2.skuid
GROUP BY t1.skuid
    ,t2.skuid;
```

The join condition should give you every unique combination of two skuids.  Then it's just a matter of counting everything